# logging info to csv file with headers - Get-aduser

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to log samaccountname, homedirectory path, date to csv file.
I saw many things on internet but didnt seem to work for me, idk why? maybe bcoz it is related to get-aduser or im using powershellv2

what Ive written is this (doesnt work though!)

```
Get-aduser -filter * -properties homedirectory | foreach {
$a = $_.samaccountname
$b = $_.homedirectory

 $details = @{            
                samaccountname      = $a     
                homedirectory       = $b        
        } 

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details  
$path = "C:\log.csv"
$results | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Help needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Get-aduser -filter * -properties homedirectory | Select SamAccountName, HomeDirectory | Export-CSV -Path C:\Log.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm not sure that I understand your situation completely, but here is an alternative method that is similar to what you were already trying to do. Maybe it will help.

```
$results = @()
Get-aduser -filter * -properties homedirectory | foreach {
    $a = $_.samaccountname
    $b = $_.homedirectory

     $details = @{            
                samaccountname      = $a     
                homedirectory       = $b        
        } 

    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details  
}
$path = "C:\log.csv"
$results | export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: hi, thanks... but I am already using get-aduser to have perform some filter function and then create homedirectories for the users who doesnt have one (i hope u understand).... so, isnt there a way in which i dont have to use another get-aduser and just inside the existing loop get the variables which contain the info that i need to export and pass it to Exoprt-csv

Comment: HI ebgreen,
your answer worked for me!
I have another query though, can u pls let me know if I want to add these $results of 3 loops , be like - $results1, $results2, $results3
and then log it into csv, what shud i do? pls help

Comment: Creat a new object with the properties that you want in the csv. Add the object to an array. Once you have all the objects in an array, export the array to CSV. Look at these cmdlets: New-Object and Export-Csv